# How to use a Pyro proxy object as a factory?

Tags: python, factory-pattern, pyro

I want to use Pyro with an existing set of classes that involve a factory pattern, i.e. an object of Class A (typically there will only be one of these) is used to instantiate objects of Class B (there can be an arbitrary number of these) through a factory method . So, I'm exposing an object of Class A as the Pyro proxy object.

I've extended the Pyro [introductory sample code](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html#simple-example) to reflect roughly what I'm trying to do. The server-side code is as follows:

```
# saved as greeting.py
import Pyro4
import socket

class NewObj:
    func_count = None
    def __init__(self):
    print "{0} ctor".format(self)
        func_count = 0
    def __del__(self):
    print "{0} dtor".format(self)
    def func(self):
    print "{0} func call {1}".format(self, self.func_count)
    self.func_count += 1

class GreetingMaker(object):
    def __init__(self):
    print "{0} ctor".format(self)
    def __del__(self):
    print "{0} dtor".format(self)
    def get_fortune(self, name):
    print "getting fortune"
        return "Hello, {0}. Here is your fortune message:\n" \
               "Behold the warranty -- the bold print giveth and the fine print taketh away.".format(name)
    def make_obj(self):
    return NewObj()

greeting_maker=GreetingMaker()

daemon=Pyro4.Daemon(host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port=8080)                                      # make a Pyro daemon
uri=daemon.register(greeting_maker, "foo")  # register the greeting object as a Pyro object

print "Ready. Object uri =", uri            # print the uri so we can use it in the client later
daemon.requestLoop()                        # start the event loop of the server to wait for calls
```

The client side code was also altered slightly:

```
# saved as client.py
import Pyro4

uri="PYRO:foo@10.2.129.6:8080"
name="foo"

greeting_maker=Pyro4.Proxy(uri)          # get a Pyro proxy to the greeting object
print greeting_maker.get_fortune(name)   # call method normally
print greeting_maker.make_obj()
```

My intention is to be able to create instances of `NewObj` and to manipulate them just as I can manipulate instances of `GreetingMaker` on the client side, but it looks as though what happens is when the `make_obj` method gets called, a `NewObj` is created on the server side, immediately falls out of scope, and is consequently garbage collected.

This is what the output looks like, server-side:

```
<__main__.GreetingMaker object at 0x2aed47e01110> ctor
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyro4-4.12-py2.6.egg/Pyro4/core.py:152: UserWarning: HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure
  warnings.warn("HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure")
Ready. Object uri = PYRO:foo@10.2.129.6:8080
getting fortune
<__main__.NewObj instance at 0x175c8098> ctor
<__main__.NewObj instance at 0x175c8098> dtor
```

... and client-side:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.12-py2.6.egg/Pyro4/core.py:152: UserWarning: HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure
  warnings.warn("HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure")
Hello, foo. Here is your fortune message:
Behold the warranty -- the bold print giveth and the fine print taketh away.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 9, in <module>
    print greeting_maker.make_obj()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.12-py2.6.egg/Pyro4/core.py", line 146, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.12-py2.6.egg/Pyro4/core.py", line 269, in _pyroInvoke
    data=self._pyroSerializer.deserialize(data, compressed=flags & MessageFactory.FLAGS_COMPRESSED)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.12-py2.6.egg/Pyro4/util.py", line 146, in deserialize
    return self.pickle.loads(data)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NewObj'
```

I suspect I could hack around this problem by having the factory class (i.e. `GreetingMaker`) keep a reference to every `NewObj` that it creates, and add a cleanup method of some sort... but is that really necessary? Am I missing something in Pyro that can help me implement this?

(edited for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across [this feature](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/servercode.html?highlight=autoproxy#autoproxying) and am using it. It is crucial for my code which uses a similar factory pattern.

**Pyro Server**

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x=5):
        self.x = x

class Server(object):
    def build_foo(self, x=5):
        foo = Foo(x)
        # This line will register your foo instance as its own proxy
        self._pyroDaemon.register(foo)
        # Returning foo here returns the proxy, not the actual foo
        return foo

#...
uri = daemon.register(Server()) # In the later versions, just use Server, not Server()
#...
```

Comment: Oh, I dont understand why nobody has upvoted this! it's such a great note.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `pyro` pickles the `NewObj` object in the server side, but it fails to unpickle it in the client side because the `NewObj` implementation is unknown to the client.

One way to fix the problem, would be to create a third module called, for example `new_obj.py` and, after that, import it in both the server and the client as follows:

```
from new_obj import NewObj
```

This will let the client unpickle the `NewObj` instance and work with it. Anyway, please note that it will be a real `NewObj` object living in the client, not a proxy to an object living in the server.